# StackOverflowError when using ViewCompat

Tags: android, android-animation, android-appcompat, viewpropertyanimator

I'm using `viewCompat` to compatible my animation to lower api (10).

But when I deploy this on emulator I get `StackOverflowError`

This is my code:

```
private void fabFadeIn(){

    if (floatingActionButton.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {

        floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ViewCompat.setAlpha(floatingActionButton, 0f);
        ViewCompat.setScaleX(floatingActionButton, 0f);
        ViewCompat.setScaleY(floatingActionButton, 0f);

        ViewCompat.animate(floatingActionButton)
                .alpha(1)
                .scaleX(1)
                .scaleY(1)
                .setDuration(300)
                .setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator())
                .setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(View view) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                        ViewCompat.animate(floatingActionButton).setInterpolator(new LinearOutSlowInInterpolator()).start();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(View view) {

                    }
                })
                .start();


    }

}
```

And this is error:

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.currentThread(Thread.java:557)
                                                                       at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:59)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRoot.getRunQueue(ViewRoot.java:3340)
                                                                       at android.view.View.removeCallbacks(View.java:5407)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.removeStartMessage(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:341)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:268)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:1249)
                                                                       at com.test.app.activities.MainActivity$2.onAnimationEnd(MainActivity.java:305)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.startAnimation(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:308)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:269)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:1249)
                                                                       at com.test.app.activities.MainActivity$2.onAnimationEnd(MainActivity.java:305)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.startAnimation(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:308)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:269)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:1249)
                                                                       at com.test.app.activities.MainActivity$2.onAnimationEnd(MainActivity.java:305)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.startAnimation(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:308)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:269)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:1249)
                                                                       at com.test.app.activities.MainActivity$2.onAnimationEnd(MainActivity.java:305)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.startAnimation(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:308)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:269)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:1249)
                                                                       at com.test.app.activities.MainActivity$2.onAnimationEnd(MainActivity.java:305)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.startAnimation(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:308)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:269)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:1249)
                                                                       at com.test.app.activities.MainActivity$2.onAnimationEnd(MainActivity.java:305)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.startAnimation(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:308)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:269)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:1249)
                                                                       at com.test.app.activities.MainActivity$2.onAnimationEnd(MainActivity.java:305)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.startAnimation(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:308)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:269)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.start(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:1249)
                                                                       at com.test.app.activities.MainActivity$2.onAnimationEnd(MainActivity.java:305)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$BaseViewPropertyAnimat
```

As you can see error goes back to `onAnimationEnd` section of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we go to the sources, we will see, that one of realisations of compatible `animate` method is:

```
@Override
public ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat animate(View view) {
    if (mViewPropertyAnimatorCompatMap == null) {
        mViewPropertyAnimatorCompatMap = new WeakHashMap<>();
    }
    ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat vpa = mViewPropertyAnimatorCompatMap.get(view);
    if (vpa == null) {
        vpa = new ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat(view);
        mViewPropertyAnimatorCompatMap.put(view, vpa);
    }
    return vpa;
}
```

So in internal compatible animations use cache of Animators attached to your view. Now let's return to your case. You have view `floatingActionButton`. And you call `ViewCompat.animate()` for it. Then in internal implementations `ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat` is created and assigned to your view. Then you `set`'ing listener for it.

After animation is finished you call `animate` again and instead of creating new `ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat` (it seems logicaly) you received previously created `ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat` with your assigned listener. And thus you have endless loop.

To fix it, you need to write something like:

```
    ViewCompat.animate(floatingActionButton)
            .alpha(1)
            .scaleX(1)
            .scaleY(1)
            .setDuration(300)
            .setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator())
            .setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                    ViewCompat.animate(floatingActionButton).setInterpolator(new LinearOutSlowInInterpolator()).setListener(null).start();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(View view) {

                }
            })
            .start();
```

In short, you need to add `.setListener(null)` to building animation in `onAnimationEnd` callback

Answer (score 2):

You call `ViewCompat.animate(floatingActionButton)` inside of `ViewCompat.animate(floatingActionButton)` so you get an endless loop:

```
   ViewCompat.animate(floatingActionButton)
....                    
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                    ViewCompat.animate(floatingActionButton).setInterpolator(new LinearOutSlowInInterpolator()).start();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(View view) {

                }
            })
            .start();
```

Comment: But when I'm using `Animator` instead of `ViewCompat` everything works okay! What's your solution, I want to show that `Interpolator` at the end of animation?